# html shows products in different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, e-commerce

I do not know the terminology for my problems. 
i am writing a (e-commerce) project to display products. I only want to display 30 products on each page. That means product 31-60 should show on the page 2. product 61-90 should show on the page3.
But now all my products show on a single page. 
May anyone give me some ideas ? What does those"pages" called in html?

For example,  the layour show look like below.

```
page    << 1 2 3.....12 >>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on Pagination tutorials . It could solve your problem ;)